# How to append a column of data to the end of text file

Tags: java, append, text-files

My problem is how to append a column of data to the end of text file.I read the file that I need to add the column of data to it and printed this column but I could not add this column to the (writer) file.

my code is as follows

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("file1.txt", "UTF-8");
      String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
               String[] columns = line.split(",");
         System.out.println("my  column : "+ columns[numberoffeatures-1] );
        }
```

An example : suppose I have a fileName1 contains the following data

```
 A, B, C, D, F
1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0
1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0, 2.0
1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 2.0
0.0, 1.0,  1.0, 1.0, 1.0
-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 , 2.0
```

After some process I got the fileName2 contains the following data

```
B, D
-1.0, 1.0, 
1.0, 0.0 
0.0, 1.0 
0.0, -1.0
1.0, 1.0
-1.0, 1.0
```

Now I need to copy the column F from fileName1 to the end of fileName2 to be liks this

```
B, D, F
-1.0, 1.0, 1.0
1.0, 0.0, 1.0 
0.0, 1.0, 2.0 
0.0, -1.0, 2.0
1.0, 1.0, 1.0
-1.0, 1.0,2.0
```

Any help is appropriated.

Comment: plz.. colud someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the last field of each line of filename1, append the column value to the line and then write it into filename2:

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename2));

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName2, false));

String line1;
while((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null){
    String[] columns = line1.split(",");

    String line2 = reader2.readLine();
    line2 += columns[columns.length - 1];

    bw.write(line2);
    bw.newLine();
}
reader1.close();
reader2.close();
bw.close();
```

Comment: thanks @robertobatts. Actually I made some thing wrong in my question. I need to take the last column from fileName1 and add it to the end of another file called fileName2 which has different data from fileName1. sorry for that

Comment: Do you want to insert the column as the last line of the new file? Or do you want to append each filed of columns to every line of fileName2?

Comment: yes I need to append each filed of columns to every line of fileName2

Comment: @aya It is helpful if you provide examples for input and the desired output. Apart from that, you should edit changes or additions directly in the question rather than in the comments.